# Disable flash for testing purposes in Internet Explorer/Firefox/Chrome

Tags: flash, testing, adobe, cross-browser

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to disable flash in Internet Explorer for testing purposes:

I'm writing a script that tests for flash (based off the information at this link - https://www.adobe.com/support/flash/how/shock/javaplugs/javaplugs02.html) and I'm hoping there is an easier way to test this than uninstalling flash. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking for the plugin usually works. If you have Flash, the program will write default code (when using Flash to generate pages to insert your swf files) that detects for  the flash plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer I don't have an idea. But as you are also asking about Firefox in the title: [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/quickjava/) is a great Firefox AddOn that allows you to disable/enable Flash (and Java, Javascript, Silverlight and CSS) with the click of a button.